# Prevent caching of non 200 responses in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

How should I go about disabling the cache of non 200 OK responses in API Gateway.

For one of our API endpoints we implemented our complementary throttle mechanism and we're sending a 429 HTTP response.

The intention is for the client to retry the request after a short time when the server is ready to fulfil it but what happens now is that the API Gateway caches the initial response and keeps sending that from cache instead.

Comment: is your client internal or public? if internal then perhaps you could delegate to client the option to invalidate cache if response he receives is anything but 200? i.e. Cache-Control: max-age=0

Comment: the client is not internal

Comment: Are you able to include a `Cache-Control` header in the response? If so it'd be worth trying to include a `private` value to see if API Gateway respects the header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the response to [Can AWS API Gateway cache invalidate specific entries based on the response content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39303410/65839), the API Gateway cache doesn't appear to have the functionality to just "sometimes" cache a result. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html) shows a way to have the *client* make a request that will ignore the existing cache (by setting `Cache-Control: max-age=0`), but doesn't show a way for the *server* to say that "this is a single-use response that shouldn't be cached.

The first thing that I think is worth trying is specifying a header like `Cache-Control: max-age=0` in your error response just to try it to see if it works. The AWS API Gateway uses CloudFront under the hood for its distribution, so it may just work.

If that doesn't work, other options include:

1. Turn off the AWS API Gateway cache. If you need a cache, set up your own caching using CloudFront or another service that allows for more fine-grained control over which responses get cached.
2. Try to move your throttling earlier in the process (I'm not sure if you're using the built-in [API Throttling features](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html)), but since you've said you "implemented" your mechanism I'm guessing you are doing it yourself in your back-end handling the requests. If you can do throttling before your caching layer (whether it's the built-in API Gateway caching or some other system), that may end up solving your problem and put less strain on your back-end request handler.
3. After sending 429 responses to the client, when the service is free to handle further requests, send your own "cache invalidation" request with `Cache-Control: max-age=0` to get the "real" value cached. Obviously, this would be a bit tricky as you'd need to know when the service is up and available to handle more requests without getting bogged down again with adding a bunch more requests as soon as it's "free" again.
4. Depending on your exact caching needs, just have a low-enough TTL in your caching settings. For example, if once throttling kicks in, it's likely to not be available again for at least 60 seconds, then having a 60 second TTL means that the 429 response will get served from the cache for that time. But, since you were just throttling anyway and thus your service is "overloaded", it may be acceptable for your situation to continue serving that 429 until the TTL expires. This would need to be the same short TTL for both "success" and "failure" responses, though.

Comment: We tested and Cache-Control: max-age=0 and Pragma headers are ignored. However, what seems to be working and I think we will end up using is #3. Thanks for all the good suggestions.

Comment: @titel: Just for completeness, you could test sending error responses with every flag you can, like `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate`. If max-age=0 doesn't work though, I don't have high hopes for it. Glad one of my suggestions worked out for you.